# Angular Router. Вернуться при навигации на два уровня выше относительно текущего маршрута

Tags: angular, маршрутизация, angular-routing

У меня есть такой путь:

```
site.ru/one/two
```

в который я перешёл вручную, то есть используя routerLink и т.д.
Теперь я хочу перейти на два уровня выше при клике, когда вызываю метод:

```
this.router.navigate(['../..'], {relativeTo: this.route})
```

и я перехожу корректно и получаю в итоге:

```
site.ru
```

Но есть один нюанс, когда я перехожу по данному пути скопировав его и вставив в адресную строку браузера и затем пытаюсь перейти на два уровня выше вызывая метод навигации, то навигация происходит на предыдущую страницу, а не на два уровня выше относительно текущего роута, как будто я вызываю window.history.back().

Возможно данный метод this.router.navigate() работает, именно, так - я не знаю. Поэтому прошу помощи в решении данного случая.

Comment: все выглядит рабочим. Может '../..' => '../../' поменять поможет? хотя и звучит бредово

Comment: Да, разницы нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, в компоненте, который передавался в модальное окно был мною написан метод:

```
window.history.back()
```

в методе ngOndestroy, что и вызывало некорректное поведение с маршрутизацией.
Теперь всё работает корректно.

Comment: Вот она зараза где крылась) Главное нашли проблему! Удачи в разработке :)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема, которую вы описали, связана с тем, как работает относительная навигация в Angular, она почти также работает на Vue и React. Метод `this.router.navigate()` с относительными путями будет зависеть от текущего URL и контекста навигации. Если вы вставляете путь в адресную строку браузера, то Angular или любой другой фреймворк не участвует в этом процессе, и браузер обрабатывает URL самостоятельно.

Чтобы решить эту проблему и перейти на два уровня выше независимо от текущего URL, вы можете воспользоваться абсолютным путем для навигации вместо относительного. Для этого вы можете использовать `/` в начале пути, чтобы указать, что вы хотите перейти к корневому пути.

Например просто вернуться к корневому `this.router.navigate(['/'])`

Comment: Не знаю в чём проблема, но пробовал и по Вашей рекомендации сделать, но ничего не выходит, либо некорректно обрабатывается маршрут, либо перенаправляет на пред. страницу. Нельзя ли как-то обработать вставляемый маршрут в адресную строку, будто переход был сделан с помощью маршрутизатора Angular?

Comment: Как я понял, задача следующая, вы вручную вставляете: `site.ru/one/two`, где `one` и `two` скорее всего динамичные (например беруться с бэка), и вам нужно по кнопке, перейти на `site.ru`, верно понял? Тогда вопрос, почему не срабатывает переход на главную страницу, судя по всему `site.ru` должен быть главным, или нет?

Comment: @Elmir да, не перенаправляет на корневой также, спасибо, за наводку, возможно, проблема, как раз таки, в этом.

Comment: Скорее всего, так как оно должно переносить в корневую если вызван метод `this.router.navigate(['/'])`, **без** `relativeTo`. А если не переходит, то проблема где-то в другом месте

Comment: Спасибо, буду копать, отпишусь как разберусь.

Comment: Добавил ответ с решением, спасибо ещё раз!